# What's wrong with this gradient descent?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, neural-network

I want to minimize `||Ah(Wx)-y||` by gradient descent where `h` us ReLU

```
s = 9
n = 99
m = 999
A = np.random.normal((n,m))
y = np.random.normal((m,1))
W = np.random.normal((n,s))

def obj_fcn(x):
    return np.linalg.norm(A.dot(np.max(W.dot(x),0))-y)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dx = 10
    max_iter = 99
    i = 0
    x = np.zeros((s,1))
    ddx = 0.00001
    ddx2 = ddx*2
    while i<max_iter:
        d_obj = (obj_fcn(x+ddx)-obj_fcn(x-ddx))/ddx2
        x = x + d_obj
        print(x)
        i = i+1
```

This gives error

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6 /Users/Chu/Documents/fun/m608.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Chu/Documents/fun/m608.py", line 21, in <module>
    d_obj = (obj_fcn(x+ddx)-obj_fcn(x-ddx))/ddx2
  File "/Users/Chu/Documents/fun/m608.py", line 11, in obj_fcn
    return np.linalg.norm(A.dot(np.max(W.dot(x),0))-y)
ValueError: shapes (2,) and (9,1) not aligned: 2 (dim 0) != 9 (dim 0)
```

What's wrong? Is there an book I can read about such issues in Python? I almost always have this kind of trouble.

Comment: This isn't a problem with Python. It's a problem with the use of the library. Read the documentation for `np.linalg.norm` (and potentially the other `np.` functions on that line) to see what the constraints are on the data they accept.

Comment: It's `W.dot(x)` that causes the problem

Comment: I'd read the docs for that then. The error seems to suggest that it requires certain dimensions for its arguments.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `W.dot(x)`? Are you trying to do the dot product of W and x? That doesn't make sense, since x is a 9x1 and W is a 1x2.

Comment: `W` is a 1x2 matrix. The first element is a random variable drawn from N(99, 1), the second is drawn from N(9, 1). `x` is a 9x1 matrix. What do you expect by dot-multiplying them?

Comment: W is a matrix of size n by s isn't it? If not, how should I generate one?

Comment: @ZHU Please see [the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html). The first argument is the median of the distribution, since you supplied a 2-tuple, it drew two variables. Try `np.random.normal(size=(n,s))`.

Comment: I see, I changed to `W = np.random.normal(size=(n,s))` but now `A.dot(np.max(W.dot(x), 0))` doesn't work

Comment: @ZHU: please read my answer and follow some of the suggestions.  Stack Overflow is not a place for hand-holding, operation by operation.  You've coded beyond your understanding of the underlying principles.    Try incremental programming: one step at a time, fixing each step before you go to the next.

Answer (score 0):

I broke down your function to individual operations and printed the inputs and results as soon as computed.  This is a very basic debugging technique; you *need* to learn this skill if you're going to program at any level beyond trivial applications.  See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.

```
def obj_fcn(x):
    print("x", x)
    print("W", W)
    wdot = W.dot(x)
    print("wdot", wdot)
    wdot = np.max(wdot, 0)
    adot = A.dot(wdot)
    print("adot", adot)
    norm_arg = adot - y   
    print("arg", norm_arg)
    result = np.linalg.norm(norm_arg)
    return result
    # return np.linalg.norm(A.dot(np.max(W.dot(x),0))-y)
```

Output:

```
x [[  1.00000000e-05]
 [  1.00000000e-05]
 [  1.00000000e-05]
 [  1.00000000e-05]
 [  1.00000000e-05]
 [  1.00000000e-05]
 [  1.00000000e-05]
 [  1.00000000e-05]
 [  1.00000000e-05]]
W [ 98.90267125   7.01706833]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so.py", line 32, in <module>
    d_obj = (obj_fcn(x+ddx) - obj_fcn(x-ddx)) / ddx2
  File "so.py", line 13, in obj_fcn
    wdot = W.dot(x)
ValueError: shapes (2,) and (9,1) not aligned: 2 (dim 0) != 9 (dim 0)
```

That shows the error clearly: you're trying to take the dot product of items of different lengths.  Dot product is not defined for such a case.  You have to fix your input processing.